# Retrieving Data from a Mapping

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix

I am having trouble accessing data from a mapping that I have created on the client side.

My smart contract has 2 function 1 that sets the values for the mapping.  The second one retrieves the values of my mapping.   When I deploy and run these functions in Remix they return the correct value.  But when I start to integrate then with my front end I am hitting some issues.

Here are the smart contract functions:

```
struct Student {
    string grade;
    address studentAddr;
    string fName;
    string lName;
    string email;
    string className;
}

mapping (address => Student) Students;

address[] public studentAccts;
```

Setter Function:

```
 function setStudent (address _address, string _grade, string _fName, string _lName, string _email, string _className) public {
    var student = Students[_address];

    //Setting the variables of my Struct. 
    student.grade = _grade;
    student.studentAddr = _address;
    student.fName = _fName;
    student.lName = _lName;
    student.email = _email;
    student.className = _className;

    studentAccts.push(_address) -1;
}
```

Then my Getter

```
function getStudent(address _address) view public returns (string, address, string, string, string, string){
    return (Students[_address].grade, Students[_address].studentAddr, Students[_address].fName, Students[_address].lName, Students[_address].email, Students[_address].className);
}
```

**Now on my the client side.** 
My Function to populate the mapping for each address.

```
    Registrar.setStudent($("#address").val(), $("#grade").val(),$("#first_name").val(), $("#last_name").val(),$("#email").val(),$("#className").val(),(err, res) =>{
      console.log("this is my result", res);
      if(err){
        console.log(err)
      } 
    });
```

Then to retrieve the values in the mapping based on a specific address:

```
  $("#Retrieve").click(function(){
    const address = $("#address").val();

    Registrar.getStudent(address, (err, res) =>{
      console.log(res);

    })

  })
```

When I call the getStudent's function in my smart contract I am getting an array that looks like this: 
["0x00000000000000000000000000000000", "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "0x00000000000000000000000000000000", "0x00000000000000000000000000000000", "0x00000000000000000000000000000000", "0x00000000000000000000000000000000"]

Not sure what I am missing here.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The contract seems to be working correctly. Are you sure `$("#address").val();` returns the correct address in your case?

Comment: @Henk You are correct - i forgot to specify TEXT as my input field so the function was being triggered incorrectly.  Thanks for looking at my question.  It should be all good now!  A fresh set of eyes always helps when debugging

Comment: you should submit and accept your own answer to this problem, so others may learn as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to specify TEXT as my input field type so the function was being triggered incorrectly. Thanks for looking at my question. It should be all good now! A fresh set of eyes always helps when debugging